# get_terms ignores orderby argument on WooCommerce product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I used the following function for listing product categories and order them by name. Since I last updated WooCommerce from 3.5.7 to 3.6.1 and this is not working any more.

It does not matter, what I write into `orderby`. The terms are ordered by id I guess, in the same order as in the backend.

I had this problem before, but then I added `'menu_order' => false` and it worked. But since the update nothing works any more.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
       'orderby'           => 'name', 
       'order'             => 'ASC',
       'parent' => 2063,
       'menu_order' => false,
       'suppress_filter' => false
   ) );
```

I Also tried to switch themes without success. 
Any help is welcome.

I use WordPress version 5.1.1 and Storefront theme version 2.4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update 2** - Solved
>
> After I reported this [issue on Github WooCommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/23466), it was clearly a bug affecting `orderby` argument when calling `get_terms()` function. It's now **approved and [patched](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/23477)**.

> **The issue is solved on Woocommerce update 3.6.2**

---

First since WordPress 4.5 taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the argument array on [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function.

**You can not** use `'menu_order'` and `'suppress_filter'` arguments, as they are **not defined** for `WP_Term_Query` Class. Instead of `'menu_order'`, you will use `'orderby'  => 'order',`.

---

Now the **allowed arguments** for WordPress [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function are listed in [`WP_Term_Query` `__construct()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/).

**So YES you can use **"`orderby`"** argument:**

- The **defaults value** is set to **`name`**.
- Accepts term fields (`name`, `slug`, `term_group`, `term_id`, `id`, `description`, `parent`), `count` for term taxonomy count, `include` to match the `order` of the $include param, `slug__in` to match the `order` of the $slug param, `meta_value`, `meta_value_num`, the value of $meta_key , the array keys of $meta_query, or `none` to omit the ORDER BY clause.

So your code should be something like:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    // 'orderby'  => 'name', // <=== Default orderby is already 'name'
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'parent'   => 2063,
) );
```

Tested and

Comment: Thanks! But it's not helping, since I am using WooCommerce and as I wrote, it is not working with the newer version. WooCommerce's default order for taxonomies is not name, it is the menu_order.

Comment: @nuriye No sorry it's "order" and not "menu_order"… see on the documentations for taxonomy (which is different from post data or post meta data). I just help as I can… but this is a bug on WooCommerce.

Comment: You are right, i looked into the database. Must be a bug by woocommerce, that the query took and changed the order when I passed menu_order ...

Comment: @nuriye Good news, the bug has been approved and patched [**Here**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/23477)… It will be on next 3.6.2 upcoming update.

Comment: @nuriye The update 3.6.2 is released and in the change log you will see: *Fix – [3.6.x] Allow default sorting of WC taxonomies to be overwritten by get_terms orderby. #23477*